# Install an ircbot that handles greetings of certain users

Tags: bots, irc, weechat

I want to greet a certain user `ffki-besucher` in a certain IRC channel.
Whenever that user logs in, it should get a special message written directly into the channel. I heard weechat is a good solution, but how can I achieve this?

### How do I install weechat on debian wheezy?

I already installed some packages:

```
apt-get install weechat-curses weechat-plugins weechat-scripts perl
```

I use this cool guide at https://weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_quickstart.en.html

Then I start weechat as user (not root):

```
weechat-curses
```

(in case you want to quit, use `/quit`)

Now I need the scripts, but I am stuck how to get this command running:

```
/script install buffers.pl
```

I also tried to load the script plugin again with

```
/plugin autoload script
```

The script plugin seems to be missing on debian! `weechat` in debian wheezy is quite old (0.3.8 which has a bug that the script plugin is  not included in the debian package)

(I tried to install weechat from jessie, but that would give dependencie problems with some pelrl libs, that go down to the kernel)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install `irssi` instead:

```
apt-get install irssi
```

su into your user and add the [trigger.pl](https://github.com/irssi/scripts.irssi.org/blob/gh-pages/scripts/trigger.pl) script. create:

```
mkdir -p ~/.irssi/scripts
cd ~/.irssi/scripts
git clone https://github.com/coekie/irssi-scripts/ coeki-irssi-scripts
ln -s coeki-irssi-scripts/trigger.pl
mkdir autorun
cd autorun
ln -s ../trigger.pl
```

Now start irssi as user

```
/connect irc.hackint.org
/join #ffki
/nick bot-rubo77
```

You can later edit your `~/.irssi/config` file to autojoin your server and channel with a certain nick:

```
{ address = "irc.hackint.net"; chatnet = "hackint"; port = "6697"; use_ssl="yes"; autoconnect="yes"; },
...
chatnets = {
  hackint = {
    type = "IRC";
    nick="bot-rubo77";
  };
};
```

change to the status window (ESC 1) and create the trigger:

```
/trigger add -joins -channels "#ffki" -masks "*ffki-b*@*" -command "msg #ffki Hi $N! Please be patient! Not everyone is at the keyboard but you will be noticed in a few minutes ..." 
/trigger save
```

some tips:

- ESC 1 - switch to status window
- ESC 2 - switch to window 2 (usually your first chat window) ...
- `/names` shows all users in the channel
- you can change the trigger in `~/.irssi/triggers` and then type `/trigger reload` in the status window

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the repository packages with

```
apt-get remove weechat*
```

and install the new packages [directly from the weechat download site](https://weechat.org/download/debian/files/#debian_wheezy_1.0.1-1_amd64) which are version 1.0.1-1:

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://weechat.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/weechat-core_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
wget https://weechat.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/weechat-curses_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
wget https://weechat.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/weechat-plugins_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
```

install guile:

```
aptget install guile-2.0-libs
```

then install the packages:

```
dpkg -i weechat-*
```

Now you can start weechat as user (not as root) and install the scripts:

```
/script install buffers.pl
/script install jnotify.pl
```

Connect to your server:

```
/server add oftc irc.oftc.net/6667
```

further set your connection like described here: https://weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_quickstart.en.html#irc_server_options

some tips:

- autocomplete with TAB or Shift-TAB
- change buffer with Alt+1 or Alt+2,...
- install `beep.pl` to send a notification through screen to your desktop (needs some configuration)
- use `/help jnotify` to achieve the auto notifications to certain users, etc