# Trigger a visitor from the Kiwi IRC Webclient

Tags: webclient, irc, irssi, kiwi-irc

I use the trigger.pl script in irssi to react on a visit by a user of our Kiwi IRC webclient. But it doesn't seem to work like it used to with another webclient before.

I use the trigger

```
/trigger add -joins -channels "#ffki" -masks "*!~ffki-besu*@*" -command "msg #ffki Hallo $N! Please be patient..."
```

How do I have to modify the trigger mask so it works with Kiwi IRC?

See [Install an ircbot that handles greetings of certain users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513470/install-an-ircbot-that-handles-greetings-of-certain-users/27557815#27557815)

Comment: Did you actually take a look at the user masks of the people coming in through that client?

Comment: In irssi I can see this: `12:47 -!- freifunk-besucher [freifunk-b@a.clients.kiwiirc.com] has joined #ffki
`

Answer (score 0):

Freenode assigns a vhost to all clients connecting, so if that's the network you're using, you can use *!*@gateway/web/cgi-irc/kiwiirc.com/*

Otherwise, you'll have to compare several users connecting to find a common element between them, and create an appropriate mask using the common elements and the mask.

Answer (score 0):

The mask can be with even more wildcards. This works:

```
/trigger add -joins -channels "#ffki" -masks "*freifunk-b*@*" -command "msg #ffki HI $N! Please be patient..."
```